# Magento: Need information for a setup script

Tags: magento

I'm trying to create a setup script to install custom attributes on my DB tables and I'm looking for references on regards to the following. I just need to know what they really do as on some of the examples I listed which I found on another question but I haven't located any information anywhere else. If someone knows where I can read about this, I'd appreciate it.

```
adminhtml_customer //to make the attribute can be created in backend only
customer_account_create //to make the attribute can be created in registration only
customer_account_edit // to make the attribute can be edited in the frontend only
customer_address_edit
customer_register_address
checkout_register
adminhtml_customer_address
```

based on the 3 first samples I listed, I can sort of guess what the others do but I do want to be mistaken about my guess and if there are others that I did not list, I'd be happy to get that information as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a look to the setup script of core code Pools (`/app/code/core/Mage`) modules, you can find a lot of good hint

Comment: The best way to learn magento is to look in the 'original' code, there are also some good screencast, about 40hr of technical stuff, on magento site ( need to subscribe to magento certification program, it should be free )